# How to install gcc7 multilib on arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, gcc, pacman, aur

I've downloaded the `gcc7` package with `pacaur -S` and that worked  fine. Now I'm looking for the gcc7 multilib package  but I can't find the pacman or aur package anywhere in the internet. Can someone send me a link or someting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, judging from the current version (gcc8), gcc is not compiled for 32-bits in Archlinux, thus not being available in multilib.

However, you can use old pacakge from Archlinux's 32-bit fork:

https://archive.archlinux32.org/packages/g/gcc/

If this doesn't work, you can always try to cross-compile it yourself:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cross-compiling_tools_package_guidelines